# Every bipartite graph is an induced subgraph of a hypercube graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, conjectures, bipartite-graphs

*UPDATE: THIS IS FALSE.*

---

I came up with this question some day and have been working on it for some time:

> Every bipartite graph $G$ is an induced subgraph of a hypercube graph $Q_n$.

Here the *hypercube graph* is a graph defined as follows:

> The hypercube graph $Q_n(V_n,E_n)$ with $V_n=\{\text{all subsets of }\{1, 2, ... , n\}\}$, $E_n=\{\{u,v\}:|u\triangle v|=1\}$, where $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

With some small examples I believe this is correct.

Here's what I've trying to do: by block decomposition we reduce to the biconnected scenario. Every biconnected graph can be constructed as follows: starting from a cycle, and adding paths to the graph. ***If** we can present* a way to add the paths in such a way that the add path itself is longer than the original distance of the two ends (in the graph before adding this path), we can always label a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ on every vertices added such that two vertices are incident if and only if the subset labelled on them has the difference of exactly one element (i.e. $|A\triangle B|=1$), because every cycle is even. (This should be true, I think) In this way we can embed this graph to some $Q_n$.

Now it remains to show the "***if***" is *true*. I tried to add the shortest path every time but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How could the embedding work for $K_{3,3}$? I think it should be a counterexample, but maybe I can't see something

Comment: @radekzak that **is** an counterexample, thanks. I couldn't believe I haven't thought about this before :D

Comment: @radekzak: You could post that as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K_{3,3}$ is a counterexample, thanks @radekzak. If a vertex is labelled $\varnothing$ then all its neighbours are singletons, and there's no appropriate choice for their another common neighbour. $\square$